# Nano not displaying correctly in term and ansi-term

Tags: ansi-term, term

Nano is displayed incorrectly in emacs when using term or ansi-term. This is what nano is supposed to look like (run in an ordinary terminal emulator):

[image]

This is nano as run from ansi-term:

[image]

In the above picture, you can see that the first line of commands is missing.

The same behavior appears in GUI and CLI mode, and running emacs with `--no-init` does not fix the problem.

Since I know the nano commands, this is only a minor nuisance, but it's pretty annoying. Is there any way I can fix this issue? I don't want to use the other terminal modes in emacs for various reasons.

Comment: Out of curiosity, why are you using a different editor from within your editor?

Comment: For writing git messages

Comment: Just for fun, I tried using Vim inside of `term`/`ansi-term` about a year ago and found that it could not properly draw all of the aspects; e.g., a particular plugin that I was interested in (`nerdtree`).  In a nutshell, someone motivated would need to spend time debugging and further improving upon `term`/`ansi-term` to achieve the results desired.

Comment: Apologies if you already know this and still prefer to use nano for commit messages, but you can set your git editor to `emacsclient`. If you do, when you call git commit from an Emacs shell, the message will open instantly in the same emacs session. And there's also magit, for even more integration with Emacs.

Comment: It works better for me -- I see both rows of commands, with the exception of the same curious blending of `^G Get Help` and `^X Exit` (which is displayed on the first row, with the area underneath being blank).

Comment: Ah, I can reproduce this in both Emacs 26 and 27 (current master), apparently it depends on window size.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's an off by one error in `term-handle-ansi-escape`, I've posted a patch in [Bug#31690](https://debbugs.gnu.org/cgi/bugreport.cgi?bug=31690).

```
--- c/lisp/term.el
+++ w/lisp/term.el
@@ -3386,11 +3386,10 @@ term-handle-ansi-escape
    ;; \E[B - cursor down (terminfo: cud)
    ((eq char ?B)
     (let ((tcr (term-current-row)))
-      (unless (= tcr (1- term-scroll-end))
+      (unless (>= tcr term-scroll-end)
    (term-down
-    (if (> (+ tcr term-terminal-parameter) term-scroll-end)
-        (- term-scroll-end 1 tcr)
-      (max 1 term-terminal-parameter)) t))))
+         (min (- term-scroll-end tcr) (max 1 term-terminal-parameter))
+         t))))
    ;; \E[C - cursor right (terminfo: cuf, cuf1)
    ((eq char ?C)
     (term-move-columns
```